# Data not converting to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am making a call to download image asynchronously in table view, and I am getting back response as well. But when I convert that data to `UIImage` using `UIImage(data:Value)` I am getting nil as output. I have verified that URL is correct by hitting in browser.

Below is my example code in cell class:

```
class BaseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var mainImageView: UIImageView!

    var object:MISArticle? {
        didSet{
            downloadFrom((object?.mainMedia()?.imageURL)!, image: mainImageView)
            print("image view size is : \(String(describing: mainImageView))")
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        }

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }



}
extension BaseTableViewCell
{
    func downloadFrom(_ link:URL,image:UIImageView)
    {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: link as URL, completionHandler: { (data, _, error) -> Void in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("\nerror on download \(error)")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("Fetching for URL \(link)")
                print("downloaded data is: \(data as NSData)")
                print("Image size is : \(image)")
                image.image = UIImage(data: data)
                print("Image after conversion : \(image.image)")

            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

OUTPUT-:

> Fetching for URL https://xxxx(it's valid)
>
> downloaded data is: {  composite, size = 176620, num_records = 3
>   record[0] = { from = 0,  length = 37336, data_object = 0x110515410 },
>   record[1] = { from = 0,  length = 90178, data_object = 0x11050ddf0 },
>   record[2] = { from = 0,  length = 49106, data_object = 0x110046420 },
>   }> Image size is :  >
>
> Image after conversion : nil

I am not getting what is wrong here, is this data valid? Or there is some other way of getting it converted? Kindly help.

Comment: What type of image this URL contains? Is it an image at all? Did you tried with some URL which point to resource `file:/pathToResorce.png`?

Comment: @Marek R it will be either JPG or PNG, and yes it's an image already verified on browser.

Comment: I tested out the code you provided on URL liniking to your avatar photo here and it worked - the image was loaded as it should be. Are you sure the image is not broken somehow?

Comment: @bevoy I am hitting the same URL on browser and i can see the image, don't know why it's not getting converted in code.

Comment: From apple docs: The data in the data parameter must be formatted to match the file format of one of the system’s supported image types. Does your url contain a file extension?

Answer (score 2):

Try to load image with this method:

```
func downloadImage(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            let urlContents = try? Data(contentsOf: url)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let imageData = urlContents else {
                    completion(nil)
                    return
                }
                completion(UIImage(data: imageData))
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i will check this.

Comment: Thanks for response, your code is fine but the images I am downloading also uses auth token that's the reason I was getting this weird response.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the cocoapod 'Kingfisher' for converting a URL to an image. You can find this here: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Then you can just use a direct link to the image and use the code below:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/image.png")
mainImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

Comment: i am already using SdWebImage in my app, and still facing the same issue. Actually i just used session for testing purpose to get  more detailed analysis. When i see error with SdWebImage it gives "Download image has 0 pixel ".

Comment: But when i run application for very first time images are loaded, after that they are never visible and i see all these error.